# Iterate through and overwrite specific values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dummy-variable

I have a large dataframe collating a bunch of basketball data (screenshot below). Every column to the right of Opp Lineup is a dummy variable indicating if that player (indicated in the column name) is in the current lineup (the last part of the column name is team name, which needs to be compared to the opponent column to make sure two players with the same number and name on different teams don't mess it up). I know several ways of iterating through a pandas dataframe (iterrows, itertuples, iteritems), but I don't know the way to accomplish what I need to, which is for each line in each column:

1. Compare the team (columnname.split()[2:]) to the Opponent column (except for LSU players)
2. See if the name (columnname.split()[:2]) is in Opp Lineup or, for LSU players, lineup
3. If the above conditions are satisfied, replace that value with 1, otherwise leave it as 0

[image]

What is the best method for looping through the dataframe and accomplishing this task? Speed doesn't really matter in this instance. I understand all of the logic involved, except I'm not familiar enough with pandas to know how to loop through it, and trying various things I've seen on Google isn't working.

Comment: In order to get help here, you would have to provide an actual example dataframe with the desired result, and explain what you have tried so far...

Comment: That's a screenshot from the variable explorer in Spyder. The desired result is to be able to loop through each value in all of the columns to the right of Opp Lineup (some 220 columns) and to be able to access the column header as well as the value for the same index in the Opponent and Lineups/Opp Lineups columns. I've tried using iterrows, itertuples, interitems to loop through in different fashions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a work around. I iterated through using df.iterrows and for each one created a list for each iteration where checked for the value I wanted and then appended the 0 or 1 to the temporary list. Then I simply inserted it to the dataframe. Possibly not the most efficient memory-wise, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a reshape/pivot solution as your data is in wide format but you need to compare values row-wise in long format. So, first [melt](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html) your data so all column headers become an actual column `'Player'` and its corresponding value to `'IsInLineup'`. Run your conditional comparison for dummy values, and then pivot back to original structure with players across column headers. Of course, I do not have actual data to test this example fully.

```
# MELT 
reshapedf = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Opponent', 'Lineup', 'Minutes', 'Plus Minus', 
                                 'Plus Minus Per Minute', 'Opp Lineup'], 
                    var_name='Player', value_name='IsInLineup')

# APPLY FUNCTION (SPLITTING VALUE AND THEN JOINING FOR SUBSET STRING)
reshapedf['IsInLineup'] = reshapedf.apply(lambda row: (' '.join(row['Player'].split(' ')[:2]) in row['Opp Lineup'] and
                                                       ' '.join(row['Player'].split(' ')[2:]) in row['Opponent'])*1, axis=1)

# PIVOT (UNMELT)
df2 = reshapedf.pivot_table(index=['Opponent', 'Lineup', 'Minutes', 'Plus Minus', 
                                   'Plus Minus Per Minute', 'Opp Lineup'], columns='Player').reset_index()
df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel(0).rename(None)
df2.columns = df.columns
```

If above lambda function looks a little complex, try equivalent apply defined function():

```
# APPLY FUNCTION (SPLITTING VALUE AND THEN JOINING FOR SUBSET STRING)
def f(row):
    if (' '.join(row['Player'].split(' ')[:2]) in row['Opp Lineup'] and \
        ' '.join(row['Player'].split(' ')[2:]) in row['Opponent']):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

reshapedf['IsInLineup'] = reshapedf.apply(f,axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually found the workaround by creating another list to append to as I iterate through to be reset to empty after iterating through each column. But this answer definitely taught me some things I wasn't aware of before

Comment: Curious though, did this example work? You might even consider maintaining a reshaped long data format as practically most analysis is better handled this way.